# Trying to write a function in Haskell and according to -Wall I need a pattern that matches (_:_:_) _ What does this pattern mean and why do I need it?

Tags: list, function, haskell, pattern-matching

So I wanted to try to make this function myself (multiples everything in a list by 3 and returns a new list):

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list2 = [3 * x | x <- list]
```

And I managed to get this using guards (basically it stops when x reaches the bound of the list):

```
tripleMultList :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
tripleMultList lst x
   | null lst = []
   | length lst - 1 == x = (lst !! x * 3) : []
   | otherwise = (lst !! x * 3) : tripleMultList lst (x + 1)
```

Then I decided to try to do it with pattern matching:

```
tripleMultList :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
tripleMultList [] x = []
tripleMultList [y] x | x == (length [y] - 1) = [y] !! x : []
tripleMultList [y] x = [y] !! x : tripleMultList [y] (x + 1)
```

But whenever I'd try to run this function I would get a non exhaustive pattern matching error so I checked ghci -Wall and it said that I needed a pattern matched to

```
(_:_:_) _
```

which I assume would take the form of

```
tripleMultList (_:_:_) _ = something
```

I'm aware that

```
(_:_:_)
```

has to do with selecting elements from a list and separating them from the list itself, though I have no idea why this would apply to my function. I also don't know what "_" means or does and how it applies to my function either.

So I guess my question is, what does this pattern mean and why do I need it when I have roughly the same thing in the version of my function which uses a guard and that one works fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function takes two arguments. GHCI is telling you that you haven't provided a definition for a function call that follows the pattern

```
tripleMultList (_:_:_) _
```

i.e. when the first argument matches the pattern `_:_:_` and the second argument matches the pattern `_`. The pattern `_` matches everything. The pattern `_:_:_` matches lists where the first element is anything, the second element is anything, and the rest of the list is anything. In other words, `_:_:_` matches lists of at least two elements.

Look at the cases you defined:

```
tripleMultList [] x = []
tripleMultList [y] x | x == (length [y] - 1) = [y] !! x : []
tripleMultList [y] x = [y] !! x : tripleMultList [y] (x + 1)
```

That's:

- First argument: empty list; second argument: anything.
- First argument: list with a single element; second argument: anything; only if `x == (length [y] - 1)` is true.
- First argument: list with a single element; second argument: anything; only if the condition above is not met.

This leaves out the case when the first argument is a list with at least two elements.

If you want to follow the decomposition in your first definition, then you need to use `y` in the second and third definitions instead of `[y]`. The pattern `y` (a variable) matches anything (of the right type) and gives it the name `y`. The pattern `[y]` matches any list of one element and gives this element the name `y`.

Comment: Meta: the use of `[x]` when just `x` was intended is a pretty common beginner mistake, for various reasons—expecting `x` to match multiple elements, or thinking of `[]` as a sigil indicating a list—and there are often questions about it here, but I can’t seem to find a standard question to point to as a duplicate. :/

Comment: @JonPurdy That is indeed one of the most frequently posted mistakes. We probably need a "canonical" reference, but no single question seems appropriate. (Maybe in the future someone will write a Q&A for that purpose only?)

Answer (score 0):

You almost never want to use `!!`, especially not for iterating over a list. Remember the definition of a list:

```
 data [] a = [] | a : [] a
```

There are only two patterns you need to match: the empty list (`[]`) and the non-empty list (`x:y`). You have the empty-list case correct: multiplying every element of an empty list yields another empty list.

```
tripleMultList [] = []
```

For a non-empty list, you need something only slightly more complicated. You have the first element `x` and the rest of the elements as `y`. All you need to do is multiply `x` by 3, and add it to the list produced by multiplying everything in `y` by 3:

```
tripleMultList (x:y) = let x' = 3 * x
                           y' = tripleMultList y
                       in x' : y'
```

Note that we can generalize this for any operation on `x`:

```
doSomething :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
doSomething _ [] = []
doSomething f (x:y) = let x' = f x
                          y' = doSomething f y
                      in x' : y'

tripleMultList = doSomething (\x -> 3 * x)
```

This type of operation is so common that `doSomething` is already defined in Haskell, but it is called `map` instead.